# Django and JQuery - Iterate through object list

Tags: jquery, django

I have a table that looks like this:

---

```
<table>
{% for object in object_list %}
<tr>
<th id="hiddenth">{{ object.user }}</th>
<th><button onclick="showTh()">Show Users</button></th>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

---

This returns a column with usernames and a column with buttons as expected.

But, all buttons are mapped to the first row of the table and the other rows are not affected.

How can I fix this?

Thank you for any help

Comment: All your `th` elements have the same ID.

Comment: That does not matter at all unless he is trying to make changes to individual rows.

Comment: @DanielRoseman that is the problem, yes. How can I access the rows individually?

Comment: @NduJay I want to toggle the rows individually. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you made it a table heading instead of a row. See correct code below.

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>User Name</th>
<th>Show User Button</th>
</tr>
{% for object in object_list %}
<tr id={{forloop.counter}}>
<td>{{ object.user }}</td>
<td><button onclick="showTh()">Show Users</button></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
</table>
```

If you want to toggle the rows with JavaScript you can use the id that is now assigned to each row by the `{{forloop.counter}}` value set on the id on each row which will be equivalent to:

1 for the first row

2 for the second row

3 for the third row

...and so on